# How to limit a long web page and how to expand it again?

Tags: php, database, loops

I am having a problem with my php web page. This page is of a vehicle selling company. The page lists down all the vehicles in the database. But if there are 100 vehicles, the page will be long and the user needs to scroll down until the end. But how can I limit all the list and display 5 by 5. I mean in the first view, user can see 5 vehicles, then if he want to see more, he could be able to click "see more" link to view the next 5 images, and so on.

The code that I am using is this. It still works. But I need the modification. So how can I do this? How can I add the "see more" link/button ? Please help me...!

```
$car = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicle_info ORDER BY id desc");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($image))
   {
  echo $row['id'];
      echo "<br>";
      echo "<img width=200 src='".$row['directory']."'>";
   }
```

Comment: Research "pagination" and maybe "AJAX pagination".

Comment: Search for "pagination" there's millions of examples showing how to do this if you look

Comment: nowadays, 'infinite scroll' is a popular way to work around pagination, see facebook, 9gag...

Comment: I am wondering why he got downvoted... Some people need to relax here, seems like he did not know the term "pagination".

Answer (score 5):

What you are searching is a **pagination**.

## the old school way

Basicaly, this is done by MySQL's **[limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)** function.

```
$car = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vehicle_info LIMIT 5,10 ORDER BY id desc");
```

Retrieves rows 6-15. A lot of people seem to struggle with the order of the *LIMIT* command. Think of it as *skip 5 rows*, *take 10 rows*.

Also, you have to add page-numbers to navigate through the results.

## the modern way

However, as stated above, there is also the option to build an **infinite scroll** using *AJAX* and a *jQuery* Plugin. In that case, you don't need to build pagenumber-links. See [this example](http://ferienfotos.hotelplan.ch/boards/index).

Comment: "infinite scroll" == AJAX pagination which is automatically triggered

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a paginator script for your mysql data, you can test this code !?

http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html